# MonoDevelop: How to start debug from Add-In

Tags: monodevelop

I'm trying to write a MonoDevelop Add-In that will start debugging.  Basically, will invoke File -> Start Debugging.  How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will start debugging on the current target:

```
IBuildTarget target = IdeApp.ProjectOperations.CurrentSelectedBuildTarget;
var operation = IdeApp.ProjectOperations.CheckAndBuildForExecute (target);
operation.Completed += delegate {
if (operation.Success)
    IdeApp.ProjectOperations.Debug (target);
};
```

Note: The `.Debug` method is an extension method so make sure that you include `MonoDevelop.Debugger` in your refs/using otherwise it will not be found...